# Missing Grid Columns

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a tab to the AR Customer screen, AR303000. The tab has a grid that will display all of the items that the customer has purchased using the following query:

```
public PXSelectJoin<ARTran,
  InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<ARTran.inventoryID, 
  Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>,
  Where<ARTran.customerID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> CustomerItemSales;
```

I have added the appropriate columns to the grid and it does display the correct records.

The issue that I am having is that not all of the selected columns are being displayed. Specifically the Transaction Date and Transaction Type fields. The fields to appear in the customization screen when I "View ASPX".

Here is the ASPX from the Customization -> Inspect Element -> Actions -> View ASPX Source menu item:

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Item Sales" RepaintOnDemand="True">
  <Template>
    <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="CstPXGrid1" AutoAdjustColumns="True" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto">
      <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="CustomerItemSales">
          <Columns>
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryItem__InventoryCD" Width="70" LinkCommand="InventoryItem_ViewDetails" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID_description" Width="200" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranDate" TextAlign="Center" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranType" Width="70" TextAlign="Center" DisplayMode="Text" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BranchID" Width="120" TextAlign="Center" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RefNbr" TextAlign="Center" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UOM" Width="70" TextAlign="Center" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Qty" Width="100" />
            <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CuryTranAmt" Width="100" />
          </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
      </Levels>
      <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinWidth="200" Container="Parent" />
      <Mode AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False" AllowUpdate="False" />
    </px:PXGrid>
  </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

What could be causing the problem and how would I debug this? I know the fields are in the data object because I have an event handler for RowSelected where I have set a breakpoint in VS and looked at the data.

Comment: my guess the fields are marked as visible false in the DAC or in the graph something is setting the visible property to false

Comment: Here are my cusomization for TranDate:

    [PXDBDate]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(ARRegister.docDate))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Transaction Date", Visible = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was going on, but I exported the project, deleted it and then imported it and it started working.